# SQL Query Returns 0 Records Eventhough Records Exist in Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a bit of a problem with one of my select queries.

I have a view on which I'm running my select query on to retrieve a set of results (through the asp.net web application using a database connect class). I do not get any results.

But rows exist in my view which match the selection criteria in my view.

And the funny thing is, if I run the same query in SQL Server Management Studio, I am getting the expected results.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Additional info:

My view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Dashboard]
AS
    SELECT     
        CBUName AS CBU, Brand AS brand, AccountName AS account, 
        DATEPART(wk, DueDate) AS Week, TeamMemeber AS [BEL Contact], 
        IsTaskCompleted AS isTaskCompleted, 
        [Contact Person] AS buyerContact, TaskType AS taskType, 
        LocationId
    FROM         
        dbo.V_ContactsToBeCompleted
    WHERE     
        (YEAR(DueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (LocationId = 1)
```

[image: Data Types of my view]

[image]

Query I'm trying to execute that returns 0 records:

```
SELECT 
    [taskType], [buyerContact], [Week] 
FROM 
    [customerRelationshipIndexDB].[dbo].[V_Dashboard] 
WHERE
    (CBU = 'EU') 
    AND (brand = 'M&S') 
    AND (account = 'M&S-T61') 
    AND ([BEL Contact] = 'gayaneew') 
    AND ([Week] BETWEEN 51 AND 51)
ORDER BY 
    [Week], [taskType], [buyerContact]
```

Comment: It looks like you trying to get counter before query is really runs. Can you run a simple query like 'select * from V_Dashboard' and checks result count to be sure that problem is not WHERE statements?

Comment: try [Week] = 51 instead of [Week] BETWEEN 51 AND 51

Comment: Is there an extra ) in (YEAR(DueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))?

Comment: hi i found the solution, i have been struggling with this for a few days and was almost about to give up on this. it has been a really silly mistake. i was migrating from one database to another database. and for this particular query i had used the old database name. :(